# If a number is represented as 1234 in base $x$ and as $1002003004$ in base $y$, what is the relationship between base $x$ and $y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If a number is represented as 1234 in base $x$ and as $1002003004$ in base $y$, what is the relationship between base $x$ and $y$?

Trying to represent both numbers in base $10$ I can see

$1\cdot x^3+2\cdot x^2+3\cdot x +4 \cdot x^0=1 \cdot y^9+2 \cdot y^6+3 \cdot y^3+4 \cdot y^0$

I notice that it seems that base $y$ is a much smaller base or that base $x$ is a cubed version of base $y$. Yet I'm not really sure about this approach.

Comment: That's it. $x=y^3$.

Comment: Don't forget $y\geq 5$.

Comment: @Arthur nicely spotted!

Comment: mhm Seb, wasn't it. must have been a journey.